# Angularfire2 - append item directly to list

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

When I `push("number")` into firebase, with angularfire2,  the number isn't  appended directly, instead it's nested inside a generated code.

**Inside Firebase Realtime Database:**

1) Initial code:

```
  "myList": {
    "0": {
      "key1": "val1"
    },
    "1": {
      "key2": "val2"
    }
  }
```

2) After `.push({"key3": "val3"})`

```
  "myList": {
    "0": {
      "key1": "val1"
    },
    "1": {
      "key2": "val2"
    },
    "-generatedcode_": {
      "key3": "val3"
    }
  }
```

Why the new object was not added directly, without nesting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are seeing is the expected behaviour. The [`push`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md#api-summary) function on AngularFire2's `FirebaseListObservable` uses the underlying Firebase API's [`push`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push), which generates a unique, sortable key:

> The unique key generated by push() are ordered by the current time, so the resulting list of items will be chronologically sorted. The keys are also designed to be unguessable (they contain 72 random bits of entropy).

`push` generates a unique key so that so that it's safe for multiple users to be pushing data into the one location. If that is not a problem and you wish to create a `"2"` key, you can do so, but you cannot do it using the `FirebaseListObservable`. You could use the underlying Firebase API:

```
firebase.database().ref("/myList/2").set({ "key3": "val3" });
```

Or you could use an AngularFire2 `FirebaseObjectObservable`:

```
let o = af.database.object("/myList/2");
o.set({ "key3": "val3" });
```

Where `af` is your `AngularFire` instance.

After performing either `set`, you should see your `FirebaseListObservable` instance updated to include the newly added data.

Comment: Good explanation of the problem. Can you also show how to not generate that push id and simply set the value of child `2`?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include two alternatives for using `"2"` as the key.

Comment: Great. And indeed: the thing about multi-user is what makes `push()` preferred in many situations.